# ¿Por que no puedo encontrar mi SP en la bd master?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de realizar una peticion a mi bd master pero no encuantra el SP que necesito.

Aqui mando a llamar mi cadena:

```
public static string Get()
    {
        string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString;

        return conexion;
    }
```

Esta es mi cadena de conexion:

```
        <add name="Conexion" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;Application Name=IntelisisET" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
public static bool ElimiarCredenciales()
    {
        bool respuesta;
        try
        {
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conexion.Get()))
            {
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "EliminarLicencias";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    respuesta = true;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            respuesta = false;
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar el SP, me sale el error de que no lo puede encontrar, saben por que ? o si estoy haciendo algo mal ? Me ayudarian mucho.

Answer (score 1):

1. Valida que estás en la misma instancia de SQL Server que tu conexión (localdb)\mssqllocaldb.
2. Verifica que coincida el nombre del procedimiento con el nombre que tienes en tu código (EliminarLicencias).

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo pude resolver y el problema es que necesitaba a fuerza un usuario y su correspondiente contraseña, de otra manera nunca entraba. `connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=sa;Password="`

Comment: En ese caso depende, si tienes autenticación con windows puedes omitirlo usando una cadena de conexión como esta: 

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Esta página puede servirte de referencia:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/